# Javascript autoclick link to a function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to auto click link which action is a javascript function. But it won't work..

```
if($submit)
{
  echo '<body  onload="setTimeout("autoClick();",1000);">';
  echo "<a id='linkToClick' onclick='return confirmDialog($id);'>clickme</a>";
  echo '</body>';
}

else
  echo 'not set';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function autoClick(){
        var myLink = document.getElementById('linkToClick');
          myLink.click();
      }
        function confirmDialog (id, callback) {
        confirmDialogCallback = callback;
        $("#idConfirmDialog").modal ("show");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem here is that you're using double quotes as both your attribute delimeter and around the parameter you are passing to `setTimeout` (note how the syntax highlighting gets all messed up here):

```
<body onload="setTimeout("autoClick();",1000);">
```

should be:

```
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1000);">
```

And in your PHP code, this would equate to:

```
echo '<body  onload="setTimeout(\'autoClick();\',1000);">';
```

Also, while this is not strictly necessary, passing a string value to `setTimeout` is not a recommended practice and should be avoided. You should pass the function itself instead:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(autoClick, 1000);">
```

And if you do that, you have one fewer pair of quotes to worry about.